# Table of content isn't generated when converting DOCX to PDF using xDocReport

Tags: java, pdf, xdocreport

I need to convert a DOCX file to PDF in Java app. I tried xDocReport lib, but it doesn't convert a table of content. In the output PDF file there is empty space instead of ToC.

[Source DOCX file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hvh8qz7en57dot/test-doc.docx?dl=0)

[Output PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nughrl9w7stk65l/test-doc.pdf?dl=0)

Here is my code, it's simple:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class DocxToPDFService {
    public void generatePDF(String srcPath, String destPath) throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument docx;

        try {
            docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(srcPath));
        } catch (IOException ioE) {
            throw ioE;
        }

        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("windows-1250");
        FileOutputStream pdf = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(docx, pdf, options);
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround to make it convert ToC?

Comment: do you still remember the solution?